# Creating sub-lists from a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a list containing sub-lists in python; like, the proper subset of a set. For example,

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]

Desired List = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you have any subsets of size 0 or 1? And is this an "I want to do this thing" question, or an "I want to learn by doing this thing" question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems you only want subsets of size 2 or more:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
A = range(1, 5)
list(chain(*(combinations(A, r) for r in range(2, len(A)))))
# [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

If you want all proper subsets, just change `range(2, len(A))` to `range(len(A))`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to get all the combinations from the list. Try using [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
desired_list = itertools.combinations(A, 2)
```